# \newcommand error

Tags: macros

I am using following new command:

```
\newcommand{\legend}[3]{

  \begin{itemize}

  \item Serial Number: #1

  \item #2

  \item #3%\href{http://#3}{#3}}

  \end{itemize}
}

\legend}{5, April 2015, *.*.com}
```

and I am getting following error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\enit@enditemize ->\enit@after
                               \endlist \ifx \enit@series \relax \else \ifnu...
l.29   \end{itemize}
```

Can some one help?

Comment: `\legend{5}{April 2015}{*.*.com}` (most probably) And welcome to TeX.SX! But there seem to be more errors

Comment: Please tell us which list related packages you are using.  Also you call to the `\legend` command makes no sense given the difinition, you want something like `\legend{A}{B}{C}` to specify the three arguments.

Comment: Note that fixing your call to `\legend`, your given code works with standard LaTeX, `enumerate`,`paralist` and `enumitem` so you need to gives a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Yes \legend{A}{B}{C} worked,

Answer (score 1):

This probably produces the requested result, at least it compiles without errors:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\legend}[3]{

  \begin{itemize}

  \item Serial Number: #1

  \item #2

  \item #3%\href{http://#3}{#3}}

  \end{itemize}
}


\begin{document}

\legend{5}{April 2015}{*.*.com}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you load package `paralist` or `enumitem` which redefine the `itemize` environment. `powerdot`itself also loads by default the package `enumerate`. The solution is not to load `paralist`